# Android app which locks apps during certain time period

Tags: android

Is there an Android app which lets you lock all phone apps such as Chrome, FB, Instagram etc between a time period? So that the user can only use their phone for calling between that time period but all the other apps will be locked? Perhaps locked with a password which the phone user will not have. Similar to how in the 90s they had software for parental lock on computer.

What I am looking for is a way to stop kids from using their phone when they are in school or during bedtime.

Answer (score 1):

[AirDroid Parental Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroidkidp&hl=en_US) is an example of an application which is focusing on this sort of functionality and is also mainly targetted for controlling children.

To have a very specific solution, you could also utilize [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) and create a profile that shows e.g. a specific message box when entering anything except chosen apps until you enter a specific password in it or within a specific time frame.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine uses [Safes Parental Control](https://www.safes.so/) and showed it to me. It's actually very accessible these days. This one has features like bedtime control and blocking unwanted apps. Although there are free options available, such as [Google Family Link](https://families.google/familylink/), etc.

I recommend having genuine conversations with your kids and making them aware of their situations before anything else.